# How to prevent calculator LCD zebra strip from failing

Tags: connector, calculator, glue

Calculator after some time gets problems on the LCD, some digits are not showing. That's due to loose (failing) zebra connectors.

Why do they fail, if they are melted in place? What can I do to prevent it?

Would using superglue on the connectors and around the LCD edges be a good idea so that the LCD doesn't move and doesn't put pressure on connectors?

It's about the connectors that normal scientific calculators have.

Comment: Superglue is probably one of the worst things you could do here. The glue vapors will get in between everything and can build an insulating layer between the zebra strip and the things it's supposed to be connecting to.

Comment: OP is asking about FFC, not Zebra. OP, start a new submission and ask a question using the term "FFC".

Answer (score 3):

The [elastomeric strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastomeric_connector) (brand name "Zebra") is held by simple axial pressure between the LCD and the PCB. That same axial pressure ensures proper connection to the PCB and LCD.

If yours falling off it's because the correct positioning of the LCD relative to the PCB was lost. For example, it may be because a plastic catch was broken.

Securing the strip with adhesive will not ensure proper contact because the axial pressure is too low. Indeed, the adhesive would interfere with the contact between the strip and the PCB or LCD. Rather, focus on ensuring that there is proper axial pressure between the LCD and the PCB.

Comment: That is NOT a "zebra"! And it is not a ribbon cable. That is an FFC (Flexible Flat Cable). Start a new submission and ask using the right terms.